# Best way to represent CSS & JS files for a big project

Tags: php, javascript, css, performance, codeigniter

What is the best way to represent CSS files for a large project

I am using **CodeIgniter** and there would be 100's of views and almost of them have different structure so I have a lot of options here but I don't know what is the best one so please help

1. Make a single file for CSS and single file for JS
2. Make a CSS file for each view and JS for each view
3. Make a simple database table to hold the associated files for
   each method

**for example**

```
id ----- method_name ---- files (I will normalize it )
1        /test/first      first.css,first.js
and so on
```

or make a PHP function get the associated files as text from PHP

**for example**

```
<?php
function get_assoc($view)
{
      switch($view):
          case '/test/first':
             echo "<script>alert(); </script><style>p{font-weight:bold;}</style>"; 
          break; 
      endswitch; 
}
?>
```

Also what about caching? Performance is a big factor.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to seperate each section reset/typograpy/forms/tables, this way I dont get lost.  Dont be afraid to use as many different files as you need ( for development purposes ).

Once your ready to go into production/live mode, grab the "build tool" from "html5boilerplate" and compress all your css into one file, same for js.  This will also minify your code and cache your files.  just keep your un-compressed files handy incase you need to do a major edit

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/reset.css" >
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/typography.css" >
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/tools.css" >
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/tables.css" >
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/forms.css" >
<link rel=stylesheet href="assets/css/plugins.css" >


<!-- Script -->
<script src="assets/js/modernizr2.0.js"></script>
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/tools.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/tables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/forms.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
```

I then like to wrap each (js) file as an object, again this helps with readability.

**example:**

```
(function($){

var ToolsObj = {

    init : function(){

        this.tooltip();
        this.tabs();
        this.pagination();
        this.alerts();
        this.dropdowns();
        this.lightbox();

    },
    tooltip : function(){

        //tooltip code
    },
    tabs : function(){

        //tabs code
    },
    pagination : function(){

    },
    alerts : function(){

        //alert messages code
    },
    dropdowns : function(){

        //dropdown-menu code
    },
    lightbox : function(){

        //lightbox code

    }


}


$(function(){

    ToolsObj.init();
});

 })(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Hope this gives you some insight into my workflow.
You may also want to check if each element exists in the document before running the objects.

Comment: That's good 
but how about making a script to write only the needed codes (CSS & JS ) on fly and then include it ?

Comment: just check to see if the element exists in the document ->> if(document.getElementById(element_id)){run code}, else create a functions.js and make all your calls inline. ie: onclick/onChange etc etc ie: <input onlick="return someFunc(params)" />

Comment: well, that's a good idea 
I will check it thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

**Database = no**

Don't use the database for this.  The CSS/JS files needed to display a view are directly tied to the source code, so keep that info in the source (particularly if you're using an SCM like Git or SVN).

**CSS/JS = presentation**

As these files are related to presentation/UI, I'd recommend delegating the "responsibility" of loading them to the views themselves.  The controllers & models shouldn't have to "know" anything about the CSS/JS required to display the view.

**Be modular**

Organize the files into discrete modular units.  Don't have a separate CSS/JS file for every view UNLESS you truly have completely separate functionality on every single view.  The more you share these files among views, the better off you'll be.

**Leverage caching, rather than fighting it**

I know it's a pain in the ass to rename a file every time you modify it, but it really is a good approach.  Using cache invalidating approaches (like URL?time=...) simply puts extra strain on the server and clients for no good reason.  Just take the two seconds to rename your "styles.css" file to "styles_v2.css".  You'll thank yourself later. (And remember, you don't have to rename it for every single dev change--only when it's stable enough for QA / production).

**Premature optimization = root of all evil**

Finally--and most importantly--NEVER PREMATURELY OPTIMIZE!  I've seen way too many people minify and gzip their asset files all the time, only to have them overhauled a few days later.  Either create a true build process, or wait until things stabilize to worry too much about the fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already make a page database call to figure out which views should be used etc? May want to have a main js and css that would be used for all pages, then individual ones linked via DB that are specifically used only by certain views.

As for caching... These files will be cached by browsers as long as they have the same request name. I typically auto-version these with a view method that looks something like:

```
function autoversion($filename) {
    $time = filemtime($filename);
    return $filename . '?v=' . $time;
}
```

If you have a build system that can version these files for you, you will get a small performance gain.

Comment: I didn't build anything yet just on papers 
when I reached this I had multiple choices so I wanted experts opinion
and for the main files this already included in my plan

Comment: @UserB there are automated build systems that will version your files for you on build, and also optimize them by taking out any white space, and putting them all into one file.

Comment: can you give me details ?
to make this on fly in production environment

Comment: @UserB http://www.brandonsavage.net/build-systems-relevancy-of-automated-builds-in-a-web-world/

Comment: Keep in mind that browsers cache these files for a reason.  Don't fight HTTP here--you might want to use `filemtime()` here (though it would create extra stat calls).  And ask yourself this question: compared to the time it took to edit the file, how much longer would it take to rename the file with a new version number too?

Comment: @landons browsers cache this for a reason, but when you make changes to your application, and they are not reflected in what the users see, this can be a serious problem. also, you wouldn't just be renaming the file, you would have to change every reference to that file, whether it be in a database, in include files, etc. in a large project with several team members, this can also be a very serious issue.

Comment: @dqhendricks true, but always invalidating is cheating.  Finding a graceful way to manage file versions can easily save 100's of MB in bandwidth and provide a much better user experience.

Comment: @landons no one ever suggested to always invalidate..?

Comment: Oops.  I glossed over your answer, which does use filemtime().  My mistake.  However, it does introduce unnecessary stat calls on the file system, which you would want to avoid for performance reasons.  Again, my bad.